# Retrieving the largest email from inbox Python

Tags: python, imaplib

How do i sort and retrieve the largest email from my Gmail Inbox without having to send multiple IMAP requests to the email servers? for example, if my gmail account has 10,000 messages, the code should not send 10,000 IMAP requests to find out the sizes of each of the messages. Any thoughts?

Comment: FYI, Gmail doesn't support the sort function in IMAPCLient package.. looking for another way..

Answer (score 2):

Is this helpful ? It comes back fast enough with only a couple of hundred messages.

```
import imaplib
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('me@gmail.com', 'SECRET)

resp,data = mail.uid('FETCH', '1:*' , '(RFC822.SIZE)')
print data
```

Gives:

```
['1 (UID 1 RFC822.SIZE 6383)', '2 (UID 2 RFC822.SIZE 35641)', '3 (UID 3 RFC822.SIZE 4787)',....
```

Comment: If i am understanding this correctly, Isn't this sending multiple `fetch` requests to the server? so essentially if i had 10,000 messages, it would send 10,000 `fetch` requests right? thus its not scalable.. Am i right?

Comment: I'm really not sure I thought it was sending the commands to the Imap server. Saying fetch the sizes of all the messages. I'd search Google for usage of RFC822.SIZE. Also that bit of code would be easy to test for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023723/imap-command-to-get-size-of-message is my first hit - fetchmail is using it. I'd suck it and see if it was me.

Comment: Reading http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501 might help if you're the sort of person who can grok specs.